# Creating multiple Excel worksheets from Access with VBA no longer works

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an Access VBA loop that creates an Excel spreadsheet with multiple worksheets using a TransferSpreadsheet command. This has worked for several years but now I only see one worksheet.
It seems to create the sheets but overwrite the previous one instead of adding another.
There are no errors and the code runs through but when the code activates the spreadsheet after the formatting has been done there is just the last sheet created.
Any ideas? Is this the result of a Microsoft update with unintended consequences?

There is a loop which runs a variable number of times creating a worksheet each time:

```
r.MoveFirst
ok = True
Do While ok
   tempMth = r!mth
   tempyr = r!yr
   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM BkgsSummarySS WHERE mth = '" & tempMth & "' AND yr = '" & tempyr & "'"
   Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(strTemp)
   qdf.SQL = strSQL
   qdf.Close
   Set qdf = Nothing

   DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, strTemp, SpLocation, True, strTemp
   DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE bkgsSummarySS SET [party date] = #01/01/2000# WHERE mth = '" & tempMth & "' AND yr = '" & tempyr & "'")
   Set r = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM bkgsSummarySS ORDER BY [Party Date] DESC")
   r.MoveFirst
   If r![party date] = #1/1/2000# Then ok = False
Loop
r.Close
db.QueryDefs.Delete strTemp
Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objApp.UserControl = True
objApp.workbooks.Open (SpLocation)
```

There are then lots of formatting lines, which all still work followed by:
objApp.Visible = True

I'm pretty sure its the Excel end that is the problem. How do I tell it to add a worksheet every time the TransferSpreadsheet command is executed - it did do this until a few weeks ago?

Comment: Without your code, what do we know?

Comment: At least for diagnostic purposes, see if exporting to a current Excel format works any differently. Excel8 would correspond to an Office_97-era version of Excel, so it could possibly be that a Windows/Office update broke something that will likely never be fixed.